# How to get YouTube classic back ('f6=8' no longer works)

Tags: youtube

I used to edit the 'PREF' cookie to include `f6=8` to keep the search-box option for add-to playlist, something I use all the time. In fact it worked just a few days ago. Today or yesterday it stopped working. Is YouTube killing off classic even for those willing to alter cookies to get it? Perhaps there is an add-on that can insert that functionality back into YouTube pages?

Comment: I did have a similar question yesterday, but it was locked by a background process when I mistakenly deleted it.

Comment: The following isn't a full answer, but you can add "&disable_polymer=1" to the end of a youtube video or playlist URL and it will revert back to the old layout. However, it will go back to the new layout as soon as you navigate out of that page and you will have to apply it again.

Comment: Thanks, that does work, perhaps a plugin could add that to the end of every YouTube URL? Lately I've been using an entire web-page search to find playlist in the saveto playlist.

Comment: i found this script and it still works:
https://cable.ayra.ch/tampermonkey/view.php?script=youtube_old_design.user.js

Comment: Thanks for the link, I'll check it out. Skimming through the js code it seems to try both polymer in the url and pref in cookies.